# /bin/magento file cannot be opened (Magento 2.1)

Tags: magento-2.1, reindex, bin-magento

I am trying to find my way to reindex the system using cli (in cms graphical interface on save and schedule corn jobs did not work). Diverse commands were tried:

```
- php /bin/magento indexer:reindex [indexer]
- php /bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Unfortunately nothing worked and returned message `"Could not open input file: /bin/magento"`.

Any advise?

**Situation:**
- Mode in developer set yesterday successfully (Today cannot open), used command: 
`php magento deploy:mode:set developer`, confirmation `"Enabled developer mode."`

- In /bin structure ran command `ls -la` shown that the Magento file is there (what I see in file structure as well).

Answer (score 4):

You should not have an **initial forward slash**. Make sure you are in root of magento directory and run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

or

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

rather than:

```
php /bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If this still does not work execute permissions are not present for bin/magento and you will get a different error 'Permission Denied'. To fix this running 'chmod u+x bin/magento' from root will fix the permissions. Now you should be able to run the 'bin/magento indexer:reindex' command.

Comment: Is there still an error?

Comment: 1. by command "php bin/magento indexer:reindex", reply "[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" and "[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory ". I think its because "bin" is a folder from root perspective and to enter it, its missing "/"; 2. by command "bin/magento indexer:reindex" I got the answer as you said "bash: bin/magento: Permission denied". To fix it I tried

Comment: to place command "chmod u+x bin/magento" direct after it in root as you told. Unfortunately, no reaction after it.. any alternative advises or how could I go around that permission issue? PS sorry @Harri had to split content due to max char limit

Comment: There wont be a reaction after changing permission it just changes it silently. Try the bin/magento indexer:reindex again now you have permission to execute bin/magento

Comment: Also if your permissions are wrong for bin/magento also will be worth looking over http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html to make sure all permissions are set corectly.

Comment: What does it say now you have set permissions?

Comment: strange... now two above commands brought "[2002] No such file or directory", after placing "php /bin/magento indexer:reindex" brought "Could not open input file: /bin/magento". :( For permissions, not sure where the complexity could hide. There is only one user - me, with admin full rights.. need to read article you link above to understand it better I guess..

Comment: that shouldn't have the initial forward slash tho still? bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: With no slash no optimistic result...after placing "bin/magento indexer:reindex". It comes with: "[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" and "[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" :( no clue... could it be installation not done properly? style sheet (styles.css) was missing as well from the beginning, what I think is not a common thing..

Comment: That is better than could not open input file that shows another problem. I think having a look here may help http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html and http://prattski.com/2010/08/05/magento-install-mysql-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: great, thank you @Harri. Will check them.

Comment: Yeah someone else has had a similar issue also see link. Fixing the php version that was used for command line fixed: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1569

Comment: great tip. in cli "Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini" any clue how to find the file "On the server upload a php file with phpinfo()"? On the root folder could not see.

Comment: the problem was actually a mix of few things. First of all I had to activate the editorial permission with "chmod u+x bin/magento" and after I got to know from hosting support that the http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html issue was due to limited/specific IP to access SSH webserver(remote) database. Now indexing and "[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000]" are overcome. Thank you for all the support!

Comment: Glad you got there in the end!

Answer (score 2):

Remove cache manually from these directories except .htaccess file:

1. pub/static (except .htaccess)
2. var/cache
3. var/di
4. var/page_cache
5. var/view_preprocessed (except .htaccess)

It will work by these only. Comment If didnt

Comment: Thank you for follow-up, @Jai. Sorry never did it before. You mean deleting all folders in the structures except ".htaccess"? Are you sure? :) in the 1st "pub/static" there are 3 sub-folders ("_requirejs", "adminhtml", "frontend"), in 2nd "var/cache" there are 8 sub-folders with "mage" begining and etc. :) all sub-folders to delete?

Comment: yes. delete all as mentioned. Only to skip .htaccess file.

Comment: good news, @Jai :) - the system survived after deleting all the structures. Static files, and other cache were flushed, re-entered to cli, but the indexing command still does not work..."bin/magento indexer:reindex" returns "bash: bin/magento: Permission denied", although I am the only user account on server (admin). Any ideas how to work around that permission (Im in development mode)? I placed in root structure "chmod u+x bin/magento", but the cli did not bring anything back...

Comment: Good. Now run these commands and let me know: "find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644"
,"find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755"
,"chmod -Rf 777 var"
,"chmod -Rf 777 media"

Comment: This will solve your problem: "chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento2" 
          => magento2 is root directory . Let me know if it didnt work

Comment: Hi dear Jai, sorry missed your answer. Here is what I got after typing your given commands: "find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
chmod: cannot access './update/vendor/symfony/finder/Tests/Fixtures/with': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'space/foo.txt': No such file or directory";

Comment: "find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod: cannot access './update/vendor/symfony/finder/Tests/Fixtures/with': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'space': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access './vendor/symfony/finder/Tests/Fixtures/with': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'space': No such file or directory"; "chmod -Rf 777" brought nothing";  "chmod -Rf 777 media" brought nothing as well.

Comment: "chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento2" brought to me chmod: cannot access '/var/www/magento2': No such file or directory. I have the site ruining on external server and installed on a subdomain to test. all commands I run on a subdomain root.

Comment: I think the problem might come from some server settings miss matching system set up definition, but not sure where to find an adjust them. When I try to run on bin/magento commands all is ok except indexer and some other. I guess it must be somewhere there an issue.

Comment: When I put "bin/magento indexer", I get "[InvalidArgumentException]         
  Command "indexer" is not defined.  
  Did you mean one of these?         
      indexer:show-mode              
      indexer:set-mode               
      indexer:reindex                
      indexer:status                 
      indexer:reset                  
      indexer:info "

Comment: When I put "/magento.ausra.ch> bin/magento indexer:info" I get 3 error messages: "[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" and "  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" and "indexer:info"

Comment: the problem was actually a mix of few things. First of all I had to activate the editorial permission with "chmod u+x bin/magento" and after I got to know from hosting support that the http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html issue was due to limited/specific IP to access SSH webserver(remote) database. Now indexing and "[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000]" are overcome. Thank you for all the support!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. Most of the time, such issues are related to hosting,permission and caching.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the file and folder permission as given in Magento 2 Docs

Files and Folder Permissions

```
cd <your Magento install dir>

find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;

chown -R :<web server group> .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

For Your Reference 
[Files and Folder Permission in Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)

Comment: have to admit that I dont know how to do it. I placed the lines one after the other, no reaction from server after entering one after the other: "find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;", then "find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;", then "chmod u+x bin/magento". Maybe I did it wrong?  What do you mean by "<web server group>" is this a root structure?

Comment: "<web server group>"  is   user group created in the server. For example  some of server have "vhosts"  as  user group.

Comment: Im on server provider(hosting company), is this still the same thing if its sharing server basis?

Comment: are you in dedicated server or shared server?  can you excute the command ls  -l and send the screenshot. Let me check and share the details how to do this.

Comment: I am on shared server. The command that you gave on root structure brought: total 896 link to ScreenShot  https://www.dropbox.com/s/kumf41nybwcyo8b/Screen%20Shot%202017-06-14%20at%2018.38.42.png?dl=0

Comment: are you logined in as which user comunara? could you please execute the comman chmod -R 0775 bin/   .  then check the  php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: yes, Im logging as comunara user. I placed in root "chmod -R 0775 bin/", but noting happened. any specifics should be expected?

Comment: cd <your Magento install dir>
 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chmod u+x bin/magento

Comment: thank you for your determination :), I placed it in and nothing came up.... after tried to reindex and got the same "Could not open input file: /bin/magento" answer :(. was that right to put all "spaghetti" at once?