# Errors on editorial commens: indexer; setup (Magento 2.1)

Tags: magento-2.1

I am struggling to reindex or run any `editorial` commands (apart changed to developer mode) via the CLI. From a feeling it could be an issue with permissions or connection between database and command files.
I get all the time get "error reports:

```
 First line: "[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]No such file or directory"                                                  
    Second line:"[PDOException]                                    
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"

As example: can check cache status (get list), but not flush it (get error above). With indexer no commands works (all brings error lines listed above), but if I place only "bin/magento indewer" in CLI then I get a listed command list: [InvalidArgumentException]         
  Command "indexer" is not defined.  
  Did you mean one of these?         
      indexer:show-mode              
      indexer:set-mode               
      indexer:reindex                
      indexer:status                 
      indexer:reset                  
      indexer:info
```

I am not a developer and relative new with Magento, could anyone help to find the issue cause and lead step by step to try solutions?
I tried by now:
- placing `chmod u+x bin/magento` to give permissions to run some queries, but maybe its not enough level?
- installed magento via a "button" click on hosting company's website on php 5.6 with API `CGI/FastCGI`.
- I tried to check settings in `app\etc\env.php` (for server status). All apart of key founded to prove and looks correct.

More about my previous ticket where we did not find a solution to reindex, but at least to call some commands out:

[/bin/magento file cannot be opened (Magento 2.1)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178945/bin-magento-file-cannot-be-opened-magento-2-1)

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database? SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" looks like your database service isn't running on the server.

Comment: yes via phpmyadmin GUI... no clue if my database runs on server, how could I check it? I think the database runs on the same server as the magento site content, but not sure. I use the hosting company that provides server and database. Let me know if I could proof smth and try some corrections to make it running.

Comment: Thank you - your hint was right. There was a specific IP demanded for SSH web server database access. After a placed adjustment in Plesk GUI it works the indexer command. Now have new challenge to overcome with set data capacity limit. Will post new question. Thank you for support!

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are trying to run indexer your command should be :

```
php bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

It will reindex all indexer

If you want to check available indexers your command should be :

```
php bin\magento indexer:info
```

If you want to reindex specific indexer your command should be:

```
php bin\magento indexer:reindex Indexer method name

Example: php bin\magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
```

If you want to check status of indexer your command should be :

```
php bin\magento indexer:status
```

If you want to check assigned mode of indexer your command should be :

```
php bin\magento indexer:show-mode
```

If you want to assign mode of indexer your command should be :

```
php bin\magent indexer:set-mode Mode Indexer method name

Example: php bin\magent indexer:set-mode realtime catalog_category_product
```

Note: there only 2 modes available `realtime` and `schedule`

For details you can check magento documentation here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

Regarding Premission :

You can follow provided permission methods in magento documentation :

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

For detailed permission you can check magento docs.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

It should be error of My Sql host that you are using for your database.

You can ask your server support for MySql host ip address and replace localhost in `app/etc/env.php` with provided ip address and it should work.

Comment: Hi dear Aman, thank you for listed commands, unfortunately they all as mentioned bring the same error message. "php" in front is optional. Any ideas how to over come the error that I mentioned? As reminder from above, error message: [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory                                                  
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: can you please run `df -h` to check free space on your server

Comment: Also run this command to check inodes on server `df -i`

Comment: run command "df -h" , answer "bash: df: command not found"

Comment: ok try to check `service mysqld status`

Comment: sorry, the command "df -i" could not be found as well. Could I check it outside the CLI? Let me search for it and get back to you.

Comment: How can I check "service mysqld status"? is there a command or via graphic UI?

Comment: just copy and past high lighted line and press enter

Comment: Most probably this is the case. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

Comment: sorry do not understand what first highlighted line you mean... I see via GUI the size now 14.6 MB and settings given for data max capacity 512 MB.

Comment: this is a great tip, this could be the point. let me check it, try few things and get back with questions, ok?

Comment: Sure check things and let me know

Comment: So, I tried few things, but I guess some step is missing as the error still the same.

Comment: First I created on root the phpinfo.php file (before it was not there). I created it with a simplest 3 line command "<?php phpinfo(); ?>". Was it right way to do it? Secondly, I saw that by run "php -i" command  in CLI the Loaded Configuration File instead of "phpinfo.php" it is shown "/etc/php.ini". The php.ini file with a comparison with long specification list in "php-i" was short, so I replaced content of php.ini with the results of command text. Any advises how to proceed further or how could I try to make it work?

Comment: it would be great if i am able to check your server configuration drop access details will check drop here https://www.amanweb.in/contact-me/

Comment: Thank you Aman! :) I just got in. It was apparently server setting problem. The host provider had a specific IP for SSH web server database access. After I placed in the setting, it all got solved. Now I have magento limited memory issue during update, but indexing is working, going to add a new ticket :) but slowly pushing forward... Thank you again for all the support!